# React native app crash if using face detector

Tags: react-native, face-detection, react-native-camera

React native app crash if i use handle face. React native camera without face detector is OK. I reinstalled, used in new project but it was.

I just open the app and it crashes even though there's no error message.

Hope fix this problem